# Prevent scheduled GitHub Actions from becoming disabled

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I am a maintainer of a few Julia GitHub repositories which use GitHub Actions for nightly CI runs, via cron. Some of these packages do not get maintenance for months but are used within the ecosystem and I'd like to keep them active. GitHub's current policy is to disable these actions when no repository activity has occurred in 60 days.

I'm wondering if there is a definition for what repository activity is to prevent actions from being disabled. Is this something as simple as commenting on an issue? Or do commits need to be pushed to the main branch?

Secondly, has anyone found a good solution for keeping repositories active? I was thinking of creating a Lambda function which runs every 59 days, and performs some form of repository activity to keep things alive. I've only found this [HackerNews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24655458) post which brings this up, however there are no comments:

> Scheduled workflows will be disabled by default in forks of public repos and in public repos with no activity for 60 consecutive days. W e’re making two changes to the usage policy for GitHub Actions. These changes will enable GitHub Actions to scale with the incredible adoption we’ve seen from the GitHub community. Here’s a quick overview:
>
> 1. Starting today, scheduled workflows will be disabled by default in new forks of public repositories.
> 2. Scheduled workflows will be disabled in public repos with no activity for 60 consecutive days.

Comment: I wrote some automations that pushes a pointless commit every couple months to resolve this at the moment, but I would love to have an official solution for this issue as well.

Comment: For anyone curious, it seems like currently only *commits* (and only commits to the main branch) are considered "activity": https://github.community/t/no-notification-workflow-disabled-after-60-days/182169/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a resolution to this issue. Instead I've implemented a hopefully temporary solution to this problem.

https://github.com/invenia/KeepActionsAlive

This package uses AWS SAM to deploy a Lambda function. The function runs every 59 days, gathering all non-forked, non-archived repos for your organization. It will then hit the [enable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#enable-a-workflow) REST API endpoint for all non-manually disabled workflows. There is functionality built in to support repos outside of an organization.

It's very rudimentary, but for those already using AWS this should help fix the problem.

Comment: Dumb questions... this seems like it's supposed to sort of reset the 60 day timeout before it happens, since you've set it to 59 days. I guess sending the `enable` command resets it, even if it's currently still enabled? Also, if that's the case, could you just run this Python script from the repo itself as another action to reset all the actions, or is GitHub smart enough to prevent that from working.

Comment: You definitely could go the route of another action keeping itself and others alive. The reason why I created this as an AWS solution is to have an easier time maintaining it. Modifying one single script is a lot easier to do than mass updating/installing scripts in every repository that we own.

We've done this previous when migrating off of TravisCI and onto GHA and it was a very slow and painful process. However, if you only have one or two repositories that you're working on this would be a better (and free) solution to have another GHA that keeps everything alive.

Answer (score 5):

I too was looking for a solution to this and I encountered a plugin on the GitHub Marketplace that may be what you're looking for. The only downside is it creates "dummy commits" to your repo, which depending on your preference, you may or may not be happy with.

Keepalive Workflow: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/keepalive-workflow

Comment: Also, see this issue about dummy commits on the above Keepalive Workflow: https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/keepalive-workflow/issues/1#issuecomment-943557200

Comment: Here's an alternative that doesn't use dummy commits, only GitHub API: https://github.com/liskin/gh-workflow-keepalive